# Build only master branch on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have my repository on `bitbucket`. I am trying to build my jenkins pipeline only when the commit (or pull request) is pushed into `master` branch.

Here are my current configurations

[image]

[image]

**Current Behavior**: Whenever I commit to any branch jenkins starts building my pipeline on master branch.

**Expected Behavior**: Jenkins should build pipeline only when commit is pushed into (only) master branch.

Please correct me which configuration I am doing wrong?

Thanks
**Note**: I am using Jenkins 2.303.1

Comment: if push is detected on branch, your jenkins build start but ends prematurely because just  master branch is allowed. Add a print some message at the beginning of your build and/or the end to validate if you branch filter is ignored.

Comment: Isn't the wildcard wrong? I'm guessing the double `**` causes it to match all sorts of things that you didn't intend it to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two bitbucket sections looking at the same repo. In one you will tell Jenkins to `Suppress automatic SCM triggering`.  In the other you will define master as a special branch.

1st section under `Behaviors` click on `Property Strategy`, select `All branches get the same properties`, and add the property `Suppress automatic SCM triggering.

2nd section under `Behaviors`, add `Filter by name (with regular expression)`, then for the regex put in `master` or even better `^master$`, and you leave the property strategy alone.